# Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class ::selection [selection]

Tags: css, selection, pseudo-element

Unknown pseudo-element or pseudo-class ::selection [selection] 
shows the error while validating in w3c validation and i have also tried in css level 3 but not solved.

please reply how to validate it in w3c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/::selection

> Right now, the ::selection CSS pseudo-element is not in any
>   specification on the standard track.

The W3C validator probably won't validate something that is non-standard.

Comment: so there isnt any other option ?

Comment: An option to what? Can you clarify why you need to pass W3C validation?

Comment: I have this problem with 'body { background: #eaeaea; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5em; color: #666; font-weight: 300; }
::selection { background: #3b8dbd; color: #fff; }'